# matching multiline using re.findall in python

Tags: python, regex

In a file Myfile: the content is as follows:

```
  username: prpadiya
  url: https://bhgerrit.ext.net.nokia.com:443/154588
  commitMessage: Handling for change in the path of cm library to /etc/opt/nokia/CMNMS/plugins.
                 NATP
  createdOn: 2020-05-22 12:52:52 IST
```

I need to match starting with "commitMessage" till any number of lines in the commit message. In the above file there is extra one line which is ending with "NATP". I used re.DOTALL but still no luck. can any one help me? My code is as follows:

```
for line in myfile:
    if re.findall("^commitMessage:\s.*[\r\n].*", line, re.DOTALL):
        print("Line is ::", line)
        msg = line.split('commitMessage:')[-1]
        print("Msg is ::", msg)
        break
```

Comment: Look, you are doing something wrong if you have `for line in myfile:` and use a regex with `re.DOTALL`

Comment: You should probably read the whole file at once and match in the full files text - or iterate the file line by line and capture lines after/including theone containing `'commitMessage'` until you hit `'createOn'`

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file as a whole single string rather than reading it line by line if you need to match some pattern across lines. Then, you need to make sure there are horizontal whitespaces at the beginning of each subsequent line after `commitMessage`.

Use `myfile.read()` and

```
(?m)^commitMessage:.*(?:\n[^\S\n].*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HfXwi6/1/). Details:

- `(?m)^`  - start of a line (`(?m)` is the inline modifier that does what `re.M` does, makes `^` match start of a line and `$` the end of a line)
- `commitMessage:` - a string
- `.*` - the rest of the line, `.*` matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?:\n[^\S\n].*)*` - any 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `\n` - a newline
  - `[^\S\n]` - a whitespace other than LF
  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Python:

```
with open(fpath, 'r') as myfile:
  print( re.findall(r'(?m)^commitMessage:.*(?:\n[^\S\n].*)*', myfile.read()) )
```

Comment: Hi wiktor, Thanks for your prompt response and explanation. Your regex working outside I mean in website "https://regex101.com/" but in my vi editor its not. I have to read a line using for loop and in that line I need to match the regex. because there are so many similar commit messages will be there in the file. Please check my total code in the next comment

Comment: with open("review.txt","r") as f1:
        for line in f1:
          if re.findall(number, line):
            next(f1)
            next(f1)
            name = next(f1).split(':')[-1]
            emailid = next(f1).split(':')[-1]
            for line in f1:
                if re.findall(r'^commitMessage:.*(?:\n[^\S\n].*)*', line, re.DOTALL):
                    msg = line.split('commitMessage:')[-1]
                    print("Msg is ::", msg)
                    break
            print(name.strip()+ " & "+ emailid.strip()+ " & "+msg)
    return name, emailid, msg

Comment: @SinghB It won't work like that. You can't read a file line by line, and then run a pattern that is designed to match a multiline block of text. Again, `re.DOTALL` makes no sense what you run a regex against a single line.

Comment: Ok.. I will check. Thank you for your support